# Springboot and react fileupload: Required request part 'image' is not present

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, axios, spring-data-jpa, postman

I dont understand whats wrong with my code.
This is the situation:

- I have a frontend with react, where I can upload an image to springboot, which then puts it in a mysql database.
- This works successfully, in both react and postman
- Then I want to add new functionality. I want it so images can have tags (so you can for example search up images by writing tags). This is a many-to-many realtionship, in that each image can have several tags, and each tag can be with several images.
- I proceed to change the code in springboot so that there is a new tag entity, and a many-to-many relationship between the tag entity and the image entity.

Aftermath:

- I try to upload an image via postman to see if things still work. The uploads in postman are succsessfull.
- I try to do a upload via the react frontend, but I get an error. I havent changed the code in the react frontend. The only thing ive done is adding a field to specify tags, but I dont actually send any axios requests with the tags.
- So despite not sending any new requests and not changing the way an image is specified for uploading, I get an error.

In springboot, this is the error that appears when I try to upload a file from reactjs:
`Required request part 'image' is not present`

I hope you can help me with this. Ive sat with this for a long time. I wouldve thought everything would still work since it still works in postman. Why would uploading an image still work in postman, but suddenly not work in react, when the code for selecting a file and uploading it hasnt changed?

This is what it looks like when I upload an image via postman
[upload via postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZUyD.png)

here are some screenshots of the console in the browser when I try to make a post requesting with an image.
[Browser console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r18FG.jpg)

- In the first image Ive entered the page
- In the second image Ive selected an image called "emo.png".
- In the third image Ive pressed the "Upload" button, to send the post request. Something quickly appears in the console before the page is automatically rendered again.
- The fourth image is after the page has rendered again.
- The fifth image shows the log in the terminal, with the error message "Required request part 'image' is not present"

This is the code in my react frontend for file uploading:

```
const UploadFile = () => {

    var formData = new FormData()

    const [image, setImage] = useState([''])
    const [tags, setTags] = useState([])
    const [imageName, setImageName] = useState('')

    {/*TAGS*/}
    function updateTags(e) {
        var dict = {"tags": e.target.value.split(" ")}
        setTags(dict)
        console.log(tags)
        console.log(imageName)
    }


    {/*FILE*/}
    const handleFile = (e) => {
        formData.append("image", e.target.files[0])
        console.log(formData)
        setImageName(e.target.files[0].name)
    }

    const uploadFile = (e) => {
        const link = "http://localhost:8080/uploadimage"

        {/* UPLOADING FILE */}
        axios.post(link, formData, {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
            }
        })
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res.data)
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
        })
    }


  return (
    <>

    <form>
        <label>Label</label>
        <input name="file" type="file"onChange={
            (e) => handleFile(e)}/>

        <br></br>
        <button onClick={(e) => uploadFile(e)}>Upload</button>
        <input onChange={(e) => updateTags(e)}></input>

    </form>
    </>
  )
}

export default UploadFile
```

This is the controller in springboot, where the requests are handeled:

```
@RestController
public class FileController {

    @Autowired
    private StorageService service;

    @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000")
    @PostMapping("/uploadimage")
    public ResponseEntity<?> uploadImage(@RequestParam("image") MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
        String uploadImage = service.uploadImage(file);
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK)
                .body(uploadImage);
    }

    @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000")
    @GetMapping("/getimage/{fileName}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> downloadImage(@PathVariable String fileName){

        byte[] imageData=service.downloadImage(fileName);
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK)
                .contentType(MediaType.valueOf(service.getType(fileName)))
                .body(imageData);

    }

    @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000")
    @PostMapping("updatetags/{fileName}")
    public ImageData updateTags(@PathVariable String fileName, @RequestBody Map<String, List<String>> tags) {
        return service.updateTags(fileName, tags);
    }
}
```

This is the code for the service, where the backend talks to the database

```
@Service
public class StorageService {

    @Autowired
    private StorageRepository repository;

    public String uploadImage(MultipartFile file) throws IOException {

        ImageData imageData = repository.save(ImageData.builder()
                .name(file.getOriginalFilename())
                .type(file.getContentType())
                .imageData(ImageUtils.compressImage(file.getBytes())).build());
        if (imageData != null) {
            return "file uploaded successfully : " + file.getOriginalFilename();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public byte[] downloadImage(String fileName){
        Optional<ImageData> dbImageData = repository.findByName(fileName);
        byte[] images=ImageUtils.decompressImage(dbImageData.get().getImageData());
        return images;
    }

    public String getType(String fileName) {
        String returnType = "";
        for (ImageData imageData : repository.findAll()) {
            if (Objects.equals(imageData.getName(), fileName)) {
                returnType = imageData.getType();
            }
        }

        return returnType;

    }


    public ImageData updateTags(String name, Map<String, List<String>> tags) {
        ImageData returnImage = new ImageData();
        System.out.println(tags);


        Set<Tag> tag_objects = new HashSet<>();
        for (String tag : tags.get("tags")) {
            Tag tagEntity = new Tag(null, tag);
            tag_objects.add(tagEntity);
        }
        for (ImageData image : repository.findAll()) {
            if (name.contains(image.getName())) {
                Set<Tag> image_tags = image.getTags();
                image_tags.addAll(tag_objects);
                image.setTags(image_tags);
                repository.save(image);
                break;
            }

        }


        return returnImage;


    }
}
```

This is the code for the entities.
ImageData:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ImageData")
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class ImageData {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;
    private String type;

    @Lob
    @Column(name = "imagedata",length = 1000)
    private byte[] imageData;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name="file_has_tag",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="image_data_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "tag_id")})
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("image_data")
    private Set<Tag> tags;
}
```

Tag;

```
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class Tag {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long tagId;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String tagName;
}
```

Ive tried searching around for a solution. The problem is that the error I got can come from all kinds of errors.
So Im kind of baffeled.

Comment: Could you use the developer tools to capture the request before and after the change and post the screenshots here?

Comment: Okey. There are now several screenshots in the post. Just click on the link "Browser console"

Comment: I meant the network tab. You want to compare the requests to find the difference. However, there are errors logged in the console which you should check as well!